# How to print the statements as follows using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am a beginner to coding 
Please let me know how to write a for loop statements in python for the following.

```
a = ['I' ,'U']
b = ['play', 'like']
c = ['piano' , 'violin']
```

so now How to print the statements as follows using for loop---

```
I like piano
U like piano
I play piano
U play piano
I like violin
U like violin
I play violin
U play violin
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nested loops. You also need to reverse the b array.

```
a = ['I' ,'U']
b = ['play', 'like']
c = ['piano' , 'violin']

b.reverse()

for i in c:
    for j in b:
        for k in a:
            print(k+" "+j+" "+i)
```